# Sonar server can not be reached at 0.0.0.0:9000

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I've installed sonar on Ubuntu 12.04 following [this guide](http://sonar-pkg.sourceforge.net/). I can start sonar in terminal, but when I try to use it as maven plugin `mvn sonar:sonar` I have error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on project portalE: Sonar server can not be reached at 0.0.0.0:9000. Please check the parameter 'sonar.host.url'. -> [Help 1]
```

I can easily open 0.0.0.0:9000 as well as localhost:9000 using browser. In pom.xml I added only:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</plugin>
```

and I have file in root directory of project (*sonar-project.properties*):

```
# required metadata
sonar.projectKey=project
sonar.projectName=Project_name
sonar.projectVersion=2.0

# optional description
sonar.projectDescription=Project description 
# path to source directories (required)
sonar.sources=src/

# The value of the property must be the key of the language.
sonar.language=java

# Encoding of the source code
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

I've never used sonar before, so please tell me if there are more configurations to do here. I read documentation, but can't see where I made mistake. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I made really stupid mistake... In maven settings.xml file I set URL to 0.0.0.0:9000, so I forgot about http://
Sorry for question that's actually that easy to answer.